# How can I connect an amplifier circuit to microphone input on a laptop?

Tags: microphone

I have a microphone TRS plug and want to connect it to a USB port on my laptop and the other end to an amplifier with a microphone connected to it. I have bought a soundcard to be able to connect the TRS plug to the USB port on the computer.

When I measure with a voltmeter the tip and ring of the TRS plug when connected to the USB soundcard both show 2.87 volts. How can I now connect this to an electret microphone with an op amp circuit I built? I know one is for voltage and the other one is the audio signal but why do both tip and ring have the same voltage?

Comment: That's how mic inputs on sound cards work. They are built to connect directly to an electret mic. We can't see what kind of amplifier circuit you built so difficult to say how to connect it to a mic input. Maybe provide schematics.

Comment: The one here https://youtu.be/ts-JqEVzvDo

Comment: Please make the question self-contained so nobody has to watch a video on external service to just find the schematics that relates to this question, as it can be removed anytime so the video might not exist tomorrow. You could at least least specify where in the 10-minute video the schematics are shown without artistic mumbo-jumbo. However, you have an electret mic and USB sound card with input for electret mics. Why do you need an op-amp circuit for?

Comment: It does not work when i connect it directly to the sound card. And I wanted to make a mic with an op amp in it as well

Comment: If it does not work, did you connect it the correct way around? You post a video of someone else doing something, but not what you do.

Answer (score -2):

I use one of these. It is a Behringer U-Control UCA222 USB Audio Interface. They work very well. The voltage levels are at the right level. You can **feed it with your microphone pre-amp output**. Nice thing it is stereo. As I understand his question he has the output of an amplifier he wants to input via a USB port, this will do just that and it will also give an output. Nice part they are inexpensive and also available on the used market. This was not intended to work directly with a Mic, he is using a preamp. He also stated he purchased a sound card, this is that on a USB cable.

[image]
I have no affiliation to Behringer but have used these for many years.

Comment: what's your affiliation with Behringer? ... please update your answer

Comment: Doesn't answer the asked question. I am sure this is a nice product and works for you. It does not seem to be useful with electret mics though.